# How to disable the built in Search dialog

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Is it possible to totally disable search functions?

The only search facility I managed to disable was on the ribbon. But since I am using a subform, the user is able to use the search box on the navigation bar or he can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to start a search.

The datasheet has 60.000 rows with 52 columns. When I start a search it takes forever.

I can disable the navigation bar, but how can I prevent the user from opening the search dialog with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the relevant form, set `KeyPreview` property to `Yes`, this causes all keys pressed to be sent to the `Form_KeyDown` event before they get processed by Ms Access.

If you catch the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> key combination and process it yourself (as in my example below), it will not open the search dialog.

```
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyCode
    Case vbKeyF
        If (Shift And CTRL_MASK) Then
            MsgBox "No search allowed!", vbCritical
        End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello E Mett.THX!!! Do you also know, if there is a way to Keep the navbar of the datashett, but disable it own searchfield?

Comment: I don't think that is possible

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable the search function for all forms, insert a SubMacro in a macro called Autokeys, and trap CTRL+F (search) and CTRL+H (search and Replace) with ^F and ^H submacro names. As Action define a simple beep or even nothing. If you want to also avoid filtering, don't forget to set in your form properties `Shortcut Menu = No`.